# Storing multiple grep parameters in a bash variable

Tags: bash, grep, escaping

I want to store multiple grep parameters in a bash variable, so I can define the parameters in the configuration section at the top of my file, and use it in multiple locations.

**How do I need to define the variable and write the grep command?**

#### Details

My first attempt

```
# CONFIG: grep parameters to further filter ...                                                                  
GREP_PARAM="-E .*"

# ...

grep "^Stop " $1 | grep $GREP_PARAM | sed "..." >>$TFILE
```

results in

> grep: ..: Is a directory

Using `.\*` or `.\\*` instead causes grep to not match anything, instead of everything.

Using `grep "$GREP_PARAM"` instead only works if `GREP_PARAM` contains a single parameter, but not otherwise; e.g. if it contains `-v .*SAT.*` or `-v .\*SAT.\*` or `-v .\\*SAT.\\*`, I get

> grep: invalid option --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what arrays were introduced to handle.

```
grep_options=(-E '.*')

grep "^Stop " "$1" | grep "${grep_options[@]}" | sed "..." >> "$TFILE"
```